# why 1D scipy.interpolate.griddata using method=nearest produces nans?

Tags: python, scipy, nearest-neighbor, interpolation

I am running scipy.interpolate.griddata on a set of coordinates that could be of many dimensions (even 1). When the coordinates are 1D the nearest method produces nans instead of the closest values when outside boundaries. An example:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

target_points = [1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.]
points = np.random.rand(50)*2*np.pi
values = np.sin(points)

interp = griddata(points, values, target_points, method='nearest')
plt.plot(points,values,'o')
plt.plot(target_points,interp,'ro')
print interp
plt.show()
```

The last value printed is a NaN. Am I doing something wrong? If this is a limitation of scipy do you have a smart workaround?

Note that linear/cubic modes are expected to give NaNs, but this should not be the case for the 'nearest' mode.

Comment: You *do* know that interpolation and extrapolation aren't the same thing, right? According to the documentation, you should be getting NaNs instead of extrapolation regardless of how many dimensions you use. If nearest-neighbor extrapolation is really what you want, then consider constructing a Voronoi diagram.

Comment: Thanks for the _kind_ remind, I know :) But as you can "extrapolate" from the documentation the 'nearest' mode should work also outside the min/max values, otherwise why the 'fille_value' parameter should "have no effect for the ‘nearest’ method". Here is an example of the correct behavior in 2D: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85503/smoothing-results-from-scipy-griddata-interpolatioin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the data is 1-dimensional, [`griddata` defers to `interpolate.interp1d`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.14.0/scipy/interpolate/ndgriddata.py#L81):

```
if ndim == 1 and method in ('nearest', 'linear', 'cubic'):
    from .interpolate import interp1d
    points = points.ravel()
    ...
    ip = interp1d(points, values, kind=method, axis=0, bounds_error=False,
                  fill_value=fill_value)
    return ip(xi)
```

So even though `method='nearest'` griddata will not extrapolate since [`interp1d` behaves this way](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html).

However, there are other tools, such as [`scipy.cluster.vq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.vq.html) (vector quantization), which you could use to find the nearest value. For example,

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.cluster.vq as vq
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

target_points = np.array([1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.])
points = (np.random.rand(50)*2*np.pi)
values = np.sin(points)
code, dist = vq.vq(target_points, points)
interp = values[code]

plt.plot(points,values,'o')
plt.plot(target_points,interp,'ro')
print interp
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hum, but why when I am in dimensions >1 I obtain values != NaNs outside min and max?

Comment: I think griddata always returns NaN when the interpolation point likes outside the convex hull. I could be wrong, though. Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, for example the code here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85503/smoothing-results-from-scipy-griddata-interpolatioin

Comment: That function indeed uses the 'nearest' mode to compensate for the NaNs given by the linear/cubic mode

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in `scipy.interpolate.griddata` because the behaviour is not according to the documentation which clearly states that the input argument "fill_value" has no effect when method is "nearest".

The output of the following line:

```
scipy.interpolate.griddata(points=np.array([1,2]), values=np.array([10,20]), xi=3, method='nearest', fill_value=-1)
```

is `array(-1.0)` which proves that the `fill_value` has an impact on the output contrary to what is stated in the documentation.